# Why don't IMG tags within A HREF tags have borders that align

Tags: html, css

`<img>` tags within `<a>` tags have existed forever.
Why don't their borders line up??

Let's say the only thing on the page is

```
<a href='#'><img src='images/x.png' border='0'></a>
```

When I look at it in the firefox debugger, they both have the same width (that of the image).

But, the image is at y=0, h=height of img.

The a tag, however, has a y of somewhere below 0 (maybe halfway-ISH down the image??) and a height that takes it a couple pixels BELOW the image.

Why the frick is THAT ??

It throws off the layout later on and makes everything confusing.

Comment: because images are inline, which places the image at the baseline of the text, which does not include the line-height.

Comment: maybe people will think the duplicate is not good, but you will find a very explained answer to understand this space https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952703/8620333

Comment: yeah, that looks to be a perfect duplicate (and the answer you linked is well-thought-out). Good find

Comment: in my defense, i DID search history, but it was kinda buried a teeny bit.  thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom of the image is by default positioned at the text baseline of the `<a>` element.  The extra space below the baseline is for descenders (the parts of letterforms that extend below, as in for example the letters p and q.)

You can align the image at the bottom of the element instead by using "vertical-align:bottom" or "text-bottom" on the image:

```css
a {border: 1px solid #00F}

img#two {vertical-align: bottom}

img#three {vertical-align: text-bottom}
```

```html
Image at baseline:
<a href='#'><img src='http://placehold.it/50x50'></a>

Image at bottom:
<a href='#'><img id="two" src='http://placehold.it/50x50'></a>

Image at text-bottom:
<a href='#'><img id="three" src='http://placehold.it/50x50'></a>
```

(The rules aren't synonymous: `text-bottom` positions the element "at the bottom of the parent element's font" and `bottom` "at the bottom of the element". Based on the question here "bottom" is probably the technically correct one, but as noted in comments below, for at least some users / browsers it can overlap the border...)

Comment: to be more correct it should be `vertical-align: text-bottom;` ... try and you will see the difference

Comment: I get identical results from 'bottom' or 'text-bottom'.  But I've added it to the answer anyway, as a valid option...

Comment: well it's not 100% identical ... with bottom the image is above the border, and with text-bottom it's not .. there is 1px of difference

Comment: The border is outside the image for both as far as I can tell (in safari and chrome, at least. Perhaps there's a browser-specific difference?)

Comment: strange, this is what i see : https://imgur.com/a/FRXD0. And if you check documentation you will see that there is a difference between both https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Ah, probably different fonts.  You're right that the rules aren't synonymous, text-bottom positions it "at the bottom of the parent element's font" and bottom "at the bottom of the element".  Based on the question here "bottom" is probably what's called for. (I'm surprised that it overlaps the border for you, though; that doesn't seem like it should be correct.)

Comment: well it's good to see that this AT LEAST confuses more people than just me.  My thanks to everybody for helpin' me out here.  Sorry to have to mark my question a dup despite your awesome answer :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the default manner in which `<a>` and `<img>` are rendered.  Anchor links are (by default) `inline` elements while images are `inline-block`.

The easiest way to address any wrapping/spacing issue is to adjust the display style.  Set your `<a>` to `inline-block` and set the child `<img>` to `block`.  Consider the following example illustration the 'default' way these elements are rendered when combined, versus when you alter their default CSS.

```css
a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid red;  
}

.correct-display {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px; /* Push the 2nd example down so the <a> border is visible on the 1st example */
}

.correct-display img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#null">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" />
</a>

<a href="#null" class="correct-display">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" />
</a>
```

Comment: i don't think the word *issue* is the good one as this is not an issue

Comment: also i don't agree a lot with your inline-block/block solution .. it works because it changes the nature of the element, i guess it's better to explain the vertical-alignment and how we can change it

Comment: i think it's at least one very practical solution that makes html behave the way you "just generally want it".  Thanks !

Comment: @StephenHazel HTML/CSS is not meant to behave **like you want** :) there is rules you simply need to understand. And it's good to understand them than finding workaround to avoid them ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yeah there are rules!  way the heck too many rules!  it's good to understand them, but i've been a web dev for 5 years now and back end dev for 20 and i still do NOT understand em all :(  I'm not sure anyone truly does...

Comment: The implication that changing the nature of an element is wrong doesn't sit well with me. We use CSS in this fashion all the time. Consider `float` or changing an element to support `flex` or collapsing a list element so that items are displayed horizontally instead of in a bullet/numeric format.